# php code doesn't enter loop (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to make a diagram with RGraph(JS). I have a user counter on my site. And now I want to make a user-statistic with this diagram.

However I created a list which should be used for every query (made a form to choose month and year).

My problem is that the code doesnt enter the loop to create the new values (Day and Count).

Any idea?

Here the code:

```
$days = 0;
$day_value = array();

//check months which have 30 days
if (in_array($month, array(4,6,9,11))) {
    $days = 30; 

}
//leapyear?
if ($month == 2) {
    if ($year%4 == 0) {
        $days = 29;
    } else {
        $days = 28;
    }
} 

//Count users for each day
for ($i=1; $i<=$days; $i++) {
    $sql = "SELECT
                 Anzahl
            FROM
                 Counter
            WHERE
                 YEAR(Datum) = '".$year."' AND
                 MONTH(Datum) = '".$month."' AND
                 DAYOFMONTH(Datum) = '".$i."'";
    if (!$result = $db->query($sql)) {
        return $db->error;
    }

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $day_value[$i] = (int)$row['Anzahl'];
} 

//delete list for new month/year
$sql = "DELETE
        FROM
            Statistics
           ";
if (!$result = $db->query($sql)) {
    return $db->error;
}

//Create list with values for each day
for ($j=1; $j<=$days; $j++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                Statistics(Day,Count)
            VALUES 
                (?, ?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    if (!$stmt) {
        return $db->error;
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $j, $day_value[$j]);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        return $stmt->error;
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Aren't there any months on your calender with 31 days? Also there are builtin functions to do calculations with date/time in php. Which would fix your error with leap year calculations (research the rules again).

Comment: Agreed... this is simply a bad plan. You are better served using the extensive date libraries and functions available in PHP (some of those are core functions, too!) -- they have already worked out all these problems so you don't have to do it. It is great that you're willing to take a crack at it, but you're trying to duplicate **years** of combined efforts from experts in the field. Not worth it when the product of all that labor is right there at your fingertips. http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.calendar.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$days` is set to 0, it only changes if `$months` is 2,4,6,9,11 so for every other value of `$month` `$days` will be 0 and not enter the for loop.

```
if (in_array($month, array(4,6,9,11))) {
//code
}
elseif ($month == 2) {
//code
}
else{
//code
}
```